# Busy Beaver unprovoable for large inputs?

Tags: computational-complexity, incompleteness, provability

From Wikipedia on the busy beaver,

> there is a true-but-unprovable sentence of the form "$Σ(10↑↑10) = n$", and there are infinitely many true-but-unprovable sentences of the form "$Σ(10↑↑10) < n$".)

My question is that for any busy beaver function its well defined and only a finite amount of things need be checked.  How then can this statement be true?

Comment: You can dress the incompleteness theorems in many ways. Which is why they are so great, no matter how fast you run and try to escape them, they will be there.

Comment: Actually, even $\Sigma (8000)$ eludes $\mathsf{ZFC}$. ([Scott Aaronson's blog](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2725).)

Comment: I suppose I could revise my question to asking for an intuitive reason or a very rough proof outline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For intuition: the $n$th Busy Beaver number is basically a bound on the time a sufficiently small halting machine can take.

In order to verify the $n$th Busy Beaver number, we must execute some algorithm to check it. Our algorithm can be executed by some halting machine (indeed, if it doesn't halt, then it's not fit for purpose because it doesn't answer "yes" or "no" to its question). But if $n$ is large enough, our checking-machine falls into the set of machines the Busy Beaver function is talking about, and we get a self-reference: the checking procedure only gets BB(n) steps to verify that it, itself, halts in fewer than BB(n) steps.

Comment: "if $n$ is large enough" This is large enough that it itself reaches some level of complexity that it reaches Godels Theorem i'm assuming. How does one then calculate the value n? Is an exact value of this uncalculatable in zfc? I imagine a yes to the second question due to the fact that otherwise it would be the first unprovable n and can therefore be proven by proving all x<n   and proving that n is unprovable proves at a higher ordinal that n is the first? Or am I missing something large?

Comment: One does not calculate the value $n$. If one could calculate the value $n$, that would imply the inconsistency of ZFC, so its value is incalculable in ZFC. You're basically right.